# Is there a difference between deleted tweets and removed tweets?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to identify a way to determine if a tweet was deleted by the user or forcefully removed by Twitter.

Is there a difference? If so, how to identify it with the Twitter web app?

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. P.S. Question about APIs are off-topic here.